# How can I sum each column of my data in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file with following data:

```
1==0==2
5==3==2
7==1==0
```

how to add the numerical value column wise. I need to summarize and print it like

```
1==0==2
5==3==2
7==1==0
13==4==4   * summation column wise (This is what I want to calculate using perl)
```

I guess you have misunderstood my question. I have edited my question again by ... i meant I have many such column in the table
13==4==4 is the summation column wise which I want add to my file.

I was able to do it for first column only but i need to learn how to for all the other columns as well.

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (TEMPTABLE,"temp_data") or die "Cannot open file\n";

my @temp_table_data=< TEMPTABLE > ;
chomp @temp_table_data;

my $total_sum;
for(my $i=0;$i<=$#temp_table_data;$i++)
{
print "$temp_table_data[$i]\n";
my @col=split('==',$temp_table_data[$i]);
for(my $m=0;$m<1;$m++)
{
$total_sum+=$col[$m];
}    
}
print "$total_sum\n";

OUTPUT:
1==0==2
5==3==2
7==1==0
13
```

I don't want to sum ROW but COLUMN.

Comment: Are you saying that '==' is your column delimiter?

Comment: yes == is my column delimiter.

Comment: i tried creating an array and capturing the data but I am not able to capture the data column wise in an array.

Comment: @Suren Don't describe what you did. Show what you did (i.e. code) and explain what you are having a problem with. I have given you a fish below but you're never going to be able to learn how to work things out if you do not put some effort to figuring out what you do not know.

Comment: @Suren what happened to the `...10` etc parts?

Comment: @sinan
Thats wht i explained again that you mistook the format by ...10 i meant there are many such column.
Here is my code where I was able to add only one column ..... I just don't know how to make it for all the columns.
I have added my code in the question itself

Comment: @Suren what you are saying is inconsistent with the fact that you added the `...10`, `...30` and `...15` to get `55` in the example you originally posted. Not that it matters much but I find it annoying that the input keeps changing.

Comment: @sinan, Actually I meant ...10,...30, and ...15 as nth column and I just tried to show the summation of that particular nth column below in my earlier post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People are trying to be pretty clever in their answers. I think it's much more clear what's going on without the tricks. You certainly don't need `pairwise`, and I think in this case it makes the code harder to follow. This is simple with just built-in Perl:

```
my @sums;

while( <DATA> ) {
   my @summands = split /==/;

   foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#summands ) {
   $sums[$i] += $summands[$i];
   }
}

print "Sums are (@sums)\n";

__END__
1==0==2
5==3==2
7==1==0
```

Comment: @Brian, your script works very nicely as well, Thanks a lot for the codes.

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do does not seem that complex. If `'=='` is your column delimiter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw<pairwise>;

our ( $a, $b );

my @totals;

while ( my $record = <DATA> ) { 
    chomp $record;
    my @data = split /==/, $record;
    push @totals, ( 0 ) x ( @data - @totals ) if @data > @totals;
    pairwise { $a += $b } @totals, @data;
 }
__DATA__
1==0==2
5==3==2
7==1==0
13==4==4
```

Comment: I wanted to to make it a self-modifying void call to pairwise: `pairwise { $a += $b } @totals, ...` but it won't let me.

Comment: @Axeman Hmmm ... If you add `my @totals = (0) x 3;` it will let you use it in void context. I am not sure if there is a good reason for the autovivified value not to be modifiable or if it is a bug.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Got it to work. I'm thinking that it probably runs quicker with the in-place increment.

Comment: Axeman: That `push` is a nice way of avoiding hardcoding the number of columns. I would vote your answer up again if I could.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a variable that can hold an array
2. Go through each line and sequentially add the values to your array
3. Repeat until done.

Comment: thanks mani but i was not able to code as per your description.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my entry

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @LineTotalsArray;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
   print $line;
   chomp $line;

   my $index=0;
   for my $val ( split /==/, $line ) {
      $LineTotalsArray[ $index++ ] += $val;
   }
}

print join('==', @LineTotalsArray), "\n";

__DATA__
1==0==2
5==3==2
7==1==0
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what $LineTotalsArray->[$index++]+=$val; means and what its doing?

Comment: *LineTotalsArray* is an array that holds the total per *column*. *index* is a helper to traverse over all the numbers (held in $val) in you input line. *+= adds* the value to the right to the value to the left.

Comment: @lexu It would have been clearer if you had used an actual array rather than array reference *and* some whitespace in your formatting.